# can't get connection to database through java class

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

i'm trying to establish connection with mysql database through file properties and then run the information from servlet. my Connection class looks like this:

```
public class pageDao {

private Connection connection;
private Statement statement;

private pageDao() {
Properties prop = new Properties();

    try {
        //Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        //Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        System.out.println("Error loading driver: " +cnfe);
    }

    try {
        try {
             //load a properties file
            prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String db = prop.getProperty("database");
        String dbuser = prop.getProperty("dbuser");
        String dbpassword = prop.getProperty("dbpassword");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(db,dbuser,dbpassword);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
private static pageDao thisDao; 

public static pageDao gedDao()
{
    if(thisDao == null)
        thisDao = new pageDao();
    return thisDao;
}

public PageData getPage(String id)
{
    PageData data = new PageData();

    try {
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from pages where id='"+id+"'");
        if(rs.next())
        {
            data.setId(rs.getString("id"));
            data.setParentid(rs.getString("parentid"));
            data.setTitle(rs.getString("title"));
            data.setTitle4menu(rs.getString("title4menu"));
            data.setKeywords(rs.getString("keywords"));
            data.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
            data.setMaintext(rs.getString("maintext"));
        }
        else 
            return null;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return data;
}
```

when i run it, it doesn't show the mistake that connection wasn't established, but when it gets to the

```
public PageData getPage(String id)  {
        PageData data = new PageData();

        try {
            statement = connection.createStatement();
```

it throws `java.lang.NullPointerException`. 
can anybody help me out with that?

Comment: wrong login at last line of second try block?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.

Comment: Per Alexander Georgii-Hemm - So the variable "connection" is null then?  Have you checked that you are using the correct port?

Comment: for me it's dirty written, why you doing it with Properties etc.? Is't better do this with `DataSource` and makes some DAOFactory for getting `connection`?

Comment: as you can see i'm doing it through DAO factory, it workds fine when i run it just derictly typing in connection = DriverManager.getConnection("local....","user","psw"); But when i run it through file property, where i store url, usernamen and password, it throws NUllPointerException.

Comment: Andrew Thompson, i think that i wrote eveything properlly in my question

Comment: @Gipsy Can you share with us what the `sysout` for `db` is? I hope you know that it must be a url to a database server. And any error stacktrace on creating a `connection` object?

Comment: @Ravinder, here is my config.properties: `dbpassword=
database=jdbc\:mysql\://localhost\:3306/listexpenses
dbuser=root
`

Comment: @Gipsy You claim that connection established as it did not throw an error. But if NPE is thrown while trying to use it, you should have debugged it by a `sysout(con..)` after `con..` is created.

Comment: On a side note: I would really suggest you to read up on  how to properly use exception handling. To put it mildly: it "sucks" big time. Not understanding exception handling is probably one of the main causes for in-stable applications and "hidden" bugs. Let me know if you need some help.

Answer (score 0):

there is no issue with code.
check your passing parameter ...

check sample

```
private Connection getConnection() {
    try {
        String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/projectmining";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        return DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, "root", "admin");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: It works, if i type it in like this, but i want to store my url, username and password in properties file and retrieve this info from there, so that my password to database wasn't written in the code. when i do it throough getProperty(), it throws the NullPointerException.

Comment: print parameters in console after getting value from property file.